# Chrome insists on keeping stale/old javascript code and won't reload the recent version

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I'm doing some very simple web dev and using chrome's debugger. The included javascript never seems to update when I modify the source. I can delete the contents of the whole file and it still loads stale code (unless I restart chrome). If I remove permissions on the file, it notices and won't load the page but when replacing permissions the old code is back. This happens both when fetching via http and the local file directly. No amount of spamming reload or [`ctrl-F5`](https://superuser.com/questions/220179/how-can-i-do-a-cache-refresh-in-google-chrome) works. I've tried clearing and manually deleting the cache and even setting the don't cache option in the developer options. I don't think chrome's in *local modifications* mode but I can never tell (this "feature" is amazingly buggy if not sometimes quite desirable). I don't have this issue in firefox but specifically want to test chrome at the moment.

**Has anyone seen this before? What are the common causes? What can I do to prevent this happening?**

I'm running fedora 18 with google-chrome 31.0.1650.39-1 - and after noting a newer version - 32.0.1700.19-1. Both have the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried a cachebuster? E.g. reference JS file with a different parameter in URL?

Comment: Chrome's probably working just fine. If cachebuster doesn't work for you, something's wrong with your JS file source.

Comment: I was using *google-chrome-beta*. I've just reinstalled *google-chrome-stable* and the problem isn't happening immediately. By cachebuster I assume you mean append `?get_request_arg=94532` or something that changes dynamically. That's a decent idea for a workaround, cheers :)

Comment: Still happening on Chrome 66.

Answer (score 17):

I think ctl-shift-r does a "hard reload," ignoring any cache.

Comment: still happening in 2017.

Comment: ya, 2019; and ctl-shift-r totally does not get chrome to pick up on the new js. There's gotta be another way.

Answer (score 0):

I normally get this problem with Dreamweaver, the new code refreshes fine in the dreamweaver window but when I wanna test on chrome it loads the old code. It generally just takes a couple refreshes for the code to catch up - I assumed the problem was because I was running the files off an appache server which could be causing the delay however it's still local